# Suppress a Text Object Based on Field Value in Object

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Text Object that contains a text string followed by a database field `Max Weight {table.field}`

I want to suppress all of the Text Object whenever {table.field} = 0.

I tried the following formula under Format Text > Common > Suppress

`if {table.field} = 0 then true else false`

What I get is the field value within the text object either on or off while the text is always suppressed. What do I need to do to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to remove the "Max Weight" label too?

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 different solutions:

1) Keeping your Max Weight label, create a new Formula in the 'Formula Fields' then enter this code:

```
if {table.field} = 0 then '' else ToText({table.field})
```

2) Supressing all text, you have to create a new Formula too, but type this:

```
if {table.field} = 0 then '' else 'Max Weight ' + ToText({table.field})
```

This second way, you will create a label that will only appears when your conditions happens, and you must replace the old TextObject with this new Formula. This will cause a blank area, because no text and no weight will show, but it looks like exactly what you need.

[image]

I just tested here and it's working. Note that both 'spaces' are in the document. Attached is an image that may help you find the formulas section. Hope you can use it.

[image]

Comment: The second solution did exactly what I wanted it to do. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that the field value is numeric with 2 decimals.  Is it possible to format the output to drop the decimals?

Comment: Yes, you can use CSTR or even ToText function in your formulas so you can format as you wish. Take a look and test this in your formula: `NumberVar result := {table.field};
cstr(result , 0);` Please consider accepting and marking the aswer as correct if it's allright.